# UISearchBar barTintColor clearColor error in iOS 8.0

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, uisearchbar, xcode6

In my app i am using `UISearchBar` in xib with `Xcode` 6. And i have given bar tin color is clear color. It's working on `iOS 7.1` below.

But main problem is in `iOS 8.0` it's not working clear color. It's displaying black color.

**See Image** :

[image]

Any one having adventurous of this issue.

Comment: Sorry.. I am asking bar tin color not backgroundcolor. I have tried programmatically also. bar.barTintColor =[UIColor clearColor];

Comment: Any having solution of this problem ?....

Comment: Same problem. Setup in code doesn't help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem in search bar so i changed the **Search style** from **default to Minimal**.

And it changed the bar style.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a 1x1 pixel transparence image as background image to UISearchBar.
It would be a dirty workaround. I think Apple should fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `UISearchBar` tint color.

```
    UISearchBar *search=[[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 100, 20)];
    [search setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    search.backgroundImage=[UIImage new];
    self.navigationItem.titleView=search;
```

[image]