# Xcode 6 search bar tint clear color becomes black?

Tags: colors, uisearchbar, ios8, xcode6, tint

I am using the Xcode 6 GM. Adding a search bar with default settings like this

[image]

Then i changed the bar tint to "Clear Color" in the attributes inspector, then it becomes this

[image]

Back to Xcode 5.1, The same bar tint color change looks more intuitive as the clear color means seeing through.

[image]

Is this some kind of bug or an expected changes by the new Xcode?

Comment: I have the same problem with Xcode6 GM. Btw, setting up batTintColor in code doesn't help. So, its not a problem of IB at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784884/uisearchbar-bartintcolor-clearcolor-error-in-ios-8-0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please Try it by change UISearchbar property **Search style** from **default to Minimal.**

Comment: +1. Its work for me, but now `UISearchBar` textfield is become transparent. i.e it takes background color of parentView. How can i set textfield color to white?

Comment: @Kampai, for that, you need to add this line -       searchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarPosition.any, barMetrics: .default)